# Excel conditional formatting for multiple words

Tags: excel, search, formatting, conditional-statements

I am trying to highlight or color words using conditional formatting in Excel.

For example, in a single column in may have over 100 rows ranging in words such as `apple`, `berry`, `water`, `blue`, `red` and `shoe`.

I am trying to highlight specific words in the cell within the column. Using that example I would like to highlight `apple`, `berry` and `red`.

Rather than doing multiple conditional formats, I am trying to do this in a single session. How would I go about doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: SO is for showing examples of programming code and asking for help with bugs. I don't know excel conditional formatting very well, but please add your example of how you would do that so far.

Comment: Conditional formatting in Excel does not highlight individual words. It's the whole cell or nothing. Also, read the help to learn how to ask a question here.

Answer (score 3):

As [teylyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447970/teylyn) pointed out, you can't highlight individual words within cells using conditional formatting. However, you can highlight the whole cell containing those words.

You'd use the custom formula option for the conditional formatting, and then choose the formatting you want to apply to those cells.

An example conditional formatting function to do this would be:

`=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("apple", A1)), ISNUMBER(FIND("berry", A1)), ISNUMBER(FIND("red", A1)))`

where `A1` refers to the active cell where you're entering the formula. This would highlight all cells containing any of the words `apple`, `berry`, or `red`.

Comment: You are encouraging the OP to keep posting bad questions by answering this one.

Comment: Umm... Sorry? I don't see what's so bad about the question. Excel formulas seem like a good fit for Stack Overflow, being code-like in nature. And the OP may not know what condition formatting is/isn't capable of.

Comment: The question is a bad one because it does not show any effort of the OP. This site is not a free coding service. We encourage people to try things and post their effort, then help them based on what they have. That yields much better learnings than requests for ready-made solutions like this question. You may want to take a look at the FAQ and help section yourself to understand the philosophy.